# ActiveRecord includes not throwing exception in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec-rails

When i try to add the some random string in active record includes is not failing instead returning the empty relation in rspec.
[image]

In development env Same is throwing error in dev rails c
[image]

Comment: you can see in the log that it is just ignored. so where is the problem?

Comment: @MarianTheisen I have updated post to show the difference in execution of same Activerecord command in development and test environment

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Rails doesn't create objects of a model at this point only a relation object will probably be created.
If you try to access any data from the collection you will get an exception.

```rb
User.includes(:junk).load
```

for example, raise the exception.

Comment: Please find the updated post of same ActiveRecord commands executed in Dev environment and test environment.

Comment: Most likely you're getting an empty array because no records in the test environment.

Comment: Made sense. Will check with data in test